# Travis sonar scanner install third party plugin

Tags: travis-ci, sonarqube-scan, csslint

I need to activate the plugin https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin
to lint css files on my project.

You can see the full source code here:
https://github.com/meilleur-monde/wp-quotes-widget

I don't know how to activate this plugin. 
do I have to activate it on the server via https://sonarcloud.io or from travis by downloading the jar and install it but where ?